# Altera III Cyclone FPGA input synchronization problem

Tags: fpga, trigger

I have a problem with the  asynchronous input signal synchronization. I am trying to make  the IIC_Slave based on Cyclone III FPGA Starter Kit.

I saw 3 cases:

1. If I do not use synchronization triggers, I can enjoy a metastable clock control that affects as a number of positive- and negative- edges in each clock front. It is shown at pic 1.
2. If I use the synchronization triggers, this number of fronts disappears (as expected) but a new bug is appeared (it look’s like a reset signal on some negative edges of the clock signal). At the same time the reset signal are not detected by oscilloscope.
3. If I use the case 2 conditions with the SignalTap generated module all works correct! But it is not a valid possibility to solve problems. (738 logic elements and 41000 memory bits are wasted)

Here are explanations for the *oscillograms*. 
The digital signal D7 – reset for the counter. The digital signals D6-D1 – bits of the shift counter. The yellow analog signal – data line from IIC. The green analog signal – clock line from IIC.

Please tell me if you have any idea about this situation. I am trying to make it works about a week and have a strong headache. I can’t even formulate a appropriate question for *google*.
[image: Case 1. No synchronize, a lots of false clocks]
[image: Case 2. Synchronized IIC signals. Unattended resets of counter]
[image: Case 3. Case 2 with SignalTap. It works correctly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's for your answer. Your answer is rignt of course. But the main problem of my project is in using IIC_Clock signal as clock for counter registers. This discussion on AlteraForum helps me to solve my problem. http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45998

Answer (score 0):

For synchronisation you need *at least* two flipflops between the pin and the logic that uses it.  Those flipflops need to be very close together (in terms of the delay between the first Q output and the second D input).  You also have to ensure that the second flipflop does not get replicated (which it might if it feeds various other logic) - if it does you get race conditions as one flipflop sees an edge just before the clock and the other sees it just after.